# es6 Map get value by index

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there a way to get value of map pair per index without iteration or exporting map pairs to array?

```
let mymap = new Map();
mymap.set('foo', 'moo');
mymap.set('voo', 'loo');
// mymap by 0,1.... index get 'moo','loo' values
```

Comment: like, mymap[0]   ?

Comment: @SeanMC yes, pretty much

Comment: No. Maps are not an indexed data structure.

Comment: That sort of breaks the purpose of a Map right? key/value pairs are designed to give the user access via the key. Are you sure you are not using the wrong data structure? Perhaps an array of object literals would better suit your use case.

Comment: @RandyCasburn indeed but since its ordered and js isn't that strong type lang I hoped there might be a small hack

Comment: Modern versions of JavaScript maintain order of Object Literals anyway as long as you don't use a key that will translate to an integer. I'll try to find the reference.

Comment: `Object.entries(Array.from(new Map([['a','sddf']]).entries()))`

Answer (score 1):

No, a JavaScript Map is not accessible via index.

You say "without exporting map pairs to array", so I'm wondering if you're worried about making a map indexable without doing so imperatively. If so, you can use:

```
Array.from(mymap)[0] // ["foo", "moo"]
```

Comment: What do you think `Array.from` does if not putting pairs in an array from iteration of the map?

Comment: Not really because I have  to convert to array and I wanted to avoid that if possible.
10x downvote  isn't mine

Comment: I'm aware that it iterates the map, but judging by the language he used, I thought there may be potential for Bat Man simply to be concerned with doing it in an imperative manner.

No worries about the downvote :)

Stack Overflow is chaotic neutral, and my answer is incorrect.